# cakephp: How add span class for label in?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

i was trying like this `<?php echo $form->label('full_name', 'Full name', array('wrap'=>'span','class' => 'required'));?>`

Expected output:

`<label for="full_name">
    Full name
       <span class="required">&nbsp;</span>
</label>`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php echo $form->label('full_name', 'Full name <span class="required">&nbsp;</span>', array());?>
```

Not sure if there's a cake way of wrapping the text inside the label in an element. But the above will give you the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this :

```
        <?php 
            echo $this->Form->label('short_link', 'Custom URL <span style="font-size:9px;"><em>(Optional)</em></span>:', array('class' => 'YOUR CLASS FOR LABEL'));

            echo $this->Form->input('short_link',array('label'=>false,'class'=>'YOUR CLASS FOR INPUT','value'=>'','size'=>'40'));
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can even simplify it a bit more by putting it inside your input element :

`<?php echo $this->Form->input('full_name', array('label'=>'<span>Full Name</span>', 'class'=>'required')); ?>`